# check if any text within cell contains the text of any cells within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, google-spreadsheets

I'm looking for an Excel formula (which ideally also works within Google Sheets) that checks whether *any part* of the text value of a given cell contains the full text value of any previous cell within the same column (can appear before or after, or just before is fine too).

Except, if the cell is blank it should not be triggered due to other cells in that column also being blank, as many cells in the column are likely to be blank and I don't want to draw attention to those.

What I'm actually looking to do is use this as a conditional format to highlight cells that contain similar words.

Example, bold words below match desired pattern:

- book
- cook
- boot
- root
- proof
- pool
- wood
- loop
- hook
- **books**
- **cookie**
- **booty**
- **spool**
- **shook**
- floor
- **bloop**
- **wormwood**

Answer (score 1):

If *book* is in A2, select A3:A18 and create a Conditional Formatting Rule based on the following formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 7, --ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A2, A3)), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeeped! Although, unfortunately, Google Sheets does not recognize the AGGREGATE function. Is there perhaps a more cross-compatible alternative?

Comment: Does gs use `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A2, A3))`?

Comment: That does not appear to work either.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A2, A3)))`